# How to set Object.prototype.somefunction is `readonly`?

Tags: javascript, object, overriding

```js
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.constructor === Object); // true
console.log(typeof obj.constructor); // function

obj['foo'] = 'bar';
obj['constructor'] = 'String';

console.log(obj.constructor === Object); // false
console.log(typeof obj.constructor); // string
```

I want to mention a case in this example: In the `obj` object, I've added a new property name `constructor` with value `String`. And the type of value is `string`.

So: `'string' !== 'function'`.

Since I override it as the second, I cannot use it like a function as the first.

That also means: some js developers (almost) don't want to declare a property which the name is `constructor` in an object. If I try to doing that, the default `constructor` would be overridden.

Same to another case:

```js
var array = [];
console.log(typeof array.forEach); // function

array['forEach'] = 'String';
console.log(typeof array.forEach); // string
```

Why doesn't js accept multiple keys with same name but difference value types?

What I want to achieve:

```
var action = {
    isDone: false,
    isDone: function (flag) {
        this.isDone = flag
    }
};

action.isDone(progressing is done);
if (action.isDone) {
    // done...
}

// 'boolean' !== 'function'
```

My questions:

**1/.** How to define new property to an object with same key? (not duplicate with another topics because `same key but differnce value types`);

**2/.** Is it the best way to prevent to override an object property? (Or `readonly` as the title)

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'constructor', {
    get: function () {
        return function () {
            // default constructor here...
        }
    },
    set: function (newValue) {
        // do nothing here...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to define new property to an object with same key? (not duplicate with another topics because same key but differnce value types);

**You can't**

> Is it the best way to prevent to override an object property?

**Sure**, but you're still probably using it wrong. And whatever code you write around it is probably bad JavaScript.

---

Whatever language you're coming from, I suggest do not try to implement other idioms in JavaScript. JavaScript is its own thing. Learn how to write idiomatic JavaScript.

Comment: I'm coming from C# :(

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {
 };

// being explicit
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'testFunction', {
  writable: false,
  value: function(){
   console.log("Print read only Function");
   return;
  } 
});

console.log(obj.testFunction.toString());


obj.testFunction();

obj.testFunction= function(){
 console.log("Override Function"); 
}

console.log(obj.testFunction.toString());
obj.testFunction();
```